# Query Caching in BigQuery

Tags: caching, google-bigquery

In Bigquery, Query cache is done automatically after 1st query and gets invalidated if dataset gets changed.

However, I want to create query cache before my first user hits.

Is there any automatic way to create and invalidate query cache in Bigquery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From BQ documentation ( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results ):
"When you run a query, a temporary, cached results table is created in a special dataset referred to as an "anonymous dataset"...
...access to anonymous datasets is restricted to the dataset owner. The owner of an anonymous dataset is the user who ran the query that produced the cached result."

According to this, the user has to run the query, to cache its results. You can't do it on his behalf.

If you need to improve the speed at which the result returns to the user, you might want consider either scheduling the query and writing the output to a table (materializing a view), using the BQ BI engine (beta) or consider extending your DWH by combining BigTable with BigQuery.

Comment: Can help me understand the nuances and the technicalities of the aforementioned point? 

Considering scheduling query, materialized view, BQ BI engine?